# Is there a way to synchronize a file across all branches?

Tags: git, github

I am trying store my dotfiles on GitHub using a bare repository. The thing is, that I want to create different branches for different desktop styles but if I had to change a value in a config, which does not change the style (for example vim plugins or the .bashrc, I would have to go through all branches and change the value everywhere.

Is there a good way to mark files to be the same on all branches?

Comment: No way. Either update the file in every branch or do cherry-pick or merge.

Comment: another solution would be to create a new branch with that file changed (branching from the earliest point it exists) and `rebase` all other branches on this, but yes, you have to touch all the branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to synchronize files across all branches. Other people have already commented that it doesn't work but there was no official answer until now.